# Generate equation from pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

What equation describes the growth pattern of this sequence:

P = 5,25,35,55,65,85,95...

Heres the diferences:

5 (20) 25 (10) 35 (20) 55 (10) 65 ...

I have tried the P = Ax + B but it doesn work since the slope varies from 20 to 10.

Thanks!!

Comment: Excluding the first "5" it is "(n+1)th prime × 5". Or you could use Lagrange interpolation $-\frac{2 x^6}{9}+\frac{16 x^5}{3}-\frac{455 x^4}{9}+240x^3-\frac{5348 x^2}{9}+\frac{2189 x}{3}-325$. There are infinite functions that match these points...

Answer (score 1):

I would say  :

$$P_n=10(n+E(\frac{n+1}{2}))+5 $$

Where $E(x)$ is the greatest integer which is less or equal to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I found this guys: $$a(n) = \frac52(-3+(-1)^n+6n)$$   Its on OEIS.org. 
( [OEIS A084957](https://oeis.org/A084967) - multiples of $5$ whose GCD with $6$ is $1$.)

Comment: FYI, I've fixed the formatting plus adding a link to OEIS page. I hope you don't mind.